# dpkg: problems with creating packages

Tags: dpkg, application-development, versions

I use dpkg to create package and distribute my app. Please, look at the example of my 'DEBIAN/control' file:

```
Package: myapp
Version: 1.0.1
Section: base
Priority: optional
Architecture:  amd64
Depends: bash (>= 2.05a-11)
Maintainer: Home <home@home.com>
Description: My test app
```

The control file of previous package differs in one line:

```
Version: 1.0.0
```

Behind the scene it works fine: package-1.0.0 files are replaced with new ones. But the problem is that the user does not get any messages like "version 1.0.0 is already installed" or "Do you really want to replace the old version with the new one?". I cannot customize the behavior of "Ubuntu Software" when installing a new version of my application.
Here is the only window displayed to the user:
[Ubuntu Software screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hP6Ne.png)

How can I inform the user that the previous version of myapp is already installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is how linux works. If you ask it to do something, it does it without much ado. For example, if you copy a file using the terminal, it will silently do. If you install a package, it will silently do it. Only when there are errors or warnings, you will hear back from the system.

It is the administrator that installs applications. Linux considers the administrator to be smart. It is up to the administrator to know what he will be installing. He/she typically will know if the software is already there and in what version.

Indeed, it is also how Software is designed. If you ask it to install a `.deb`, it will do so. You would need to provide your own package manager or patch "Software" if you would want to implement confirmation dialogs.